# List All vocabularies and their terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

How can i list my vocabularies and their terms in this way . Is there a module that can help me to do this . or i should go with custom VIEW and jQuery.

[image]

thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do with [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module.

> This module provides an expandable tree widget for the Taxonomy Term
>   Reference field in Drupal 7. This widget is intended to serve as a
>   replacement for Drupal's core Taxonomy Term Reference widget, which is
>   a flat list of radio buttons or checkboxes and not necessarily fit for
>   medium to large taxonomy trees.

Comment: thanks @Bala, but this module replaces the core taxonomy widget for drupal admin . i am looking for some thing at front end .
more over to it , it will take only one vocabulary and display the terms under it , but i am looking for some thing which will take all vocabularies and list them with all their terms :)